# HttpClient, Log4J and Maven jar conflicts

Tags: java, maven, logging, log4j, apache-httpcomponents

I have a Maven POM file using org.apache.httpcomponents wich includes commons-logging (I don't need to include this dependency)

But I need to use Log4J, and it's causing conflicts by including commons-logging JAR and Log4J JARS in same project.

This conflict causing duplicating lines in my log file.

My POM (extract):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-beta5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-beta5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
</dependency>       

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient-cache</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

I try to put an **exclusion** tag in org.apache.httpcomponents for commons-loggin, but I got a Runtime error in HttpClient class (no compile error).

What can I do?

Comment: The annoying duplicated lines in log file! I don't know how, but calling `logger.debug("foo")` is writing two "foo" lines in log file.

Comment: This only lists dependencies, not their configuration or usages. You need to show the logger configurations and how you use them to get an accurate answer.

Comment: Im sure this behaviour is because I have 2 loggers (Log4J and commons-loggin) because this happens before and I was able to remove commons-logging. Now I'm unable to remove commons-logging because it is dependency for httpClient (Im not adding commons-logging by myself). BTW, if I remove httpClient and all dependencies (including commons-logging) the log show just one line, the correct behaviour).

Comment: @Ryan J you're wright after all. Sorry for my **sure** above. I'll upvote your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my fault!

Seems the specific class logger is stacked with root logger.

First log line is for specific class logger ( the logger called by class name ) and second line (duplicate) is for root logger. This is my log4j XML config:

```
<loggers>
    <Logger name="cmabreu.sagitarii.teapot.Main" level="debug"> 
        <appender-ref ref="File"/> 
    </Logger>

    <root level="error">
        <appender-ref ref="File" />
    </root>
</loggers>
```

I need to add `additivity="false"` for specific logger (cmabreu.sagitarii.teapot.Main), this way it will not stack with root logger.

```
<Logger name="cmabreu.sagitarii.teapot.Main" level="debug" additivity="false">
```